# Recover the holomorphic function from one of its components using Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

I got two similar questions:

1. Find the holomorphic function $f(x+iy)$ if
   $\Re(f(x+iy))=x(3-2y)\text{ and }f(i)=2i$
2. Find the holomorphic function $f(x+iy)$ if
   $\Im(f(x+iy))=3(x-1)^2y-y^3\text{ and }f(0)=1$

I tried both using this [source](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144503432151) but got problem at the end.
My steps for the first one :

$$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = 3-2y = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = -2x =- \frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Now integrate both
$$\int 3-2y\ dy = 3y-y^2 + g(x) = v$$
$$\int 2x\ dx = x^2 + h(y) = v$$

And now I should compare but mine v's are not equal. What am I missing, what to do with g(x) and h(y) and how to use $f(i)=2i$

Comment: Presumably, that's two different questions - find an $f$ that matches (a) then find a different $f$ that matches (b)? Not:  "Find a single $f$ that matches both (a) and (b)."

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: Also, note that $\int 2xdy = 2xy + h(x)$, not $x^2+h(y)$.

Comment: Thanks, should be dx there. I'm new here, and don't know how to put text into neat lines.

Comment: Also, $\int (3-2y)dy = 3y-y^2$, not $3y-2y^2$.

Comment: That's right, but that still leaves me with a problem unsolved.

Comment: I'm just helping you get the stuff you've already worked on right. I'm always surprised when people who are asking questions here insist on belitliing the help they get in cleaning up their question because it doesn't give them an answer.

Comment: Oh, no, I'm sorry. I didn't mean to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate first one 
$$\int 3-2y\ dy = 3y-y^2 + g(x) = v$$
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=g'(x)$$
compare it to $\frac{du}{dx}$ from above
$$\frac{du}{dx}=g'(x)=-2x$$
$$g(x)=\int-2xdx=x^2 +c $$
$$v(x,y)=3y-y^2+x^2 +c$$
$$f(x+iy)=f(i)=2i \quad=> \quad x=0, y=1$$
$$f(i)=i(3-1+c)=2i\quad=>\quad c=0$$
Finally
$$v(x,y)=3y-y^2+x^2$$
$$f(x,y)=x(3−2y)+i(3y-y^2+x^2)$$

As for the second example should be similar but I failed to get reasonable answer.